# MongoDB embedded document BSON ID

Tags: ruby, mongodb

I have a webapp where I'm created an embedded document for educations. The job document looks something like this:

```
"educations" : [
    {
        "school" : "Brandywine High School",
        "major" : "Testingasdf",
        "grad_year" : ISODate("1979-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
        "school_type" : "Graduate",
        "_id" : ObjectId("4fb26c9ce5be08208b000ce4")
    }
],
"email" : "user@domain.com",
```

The education hash has the details of the job. I noticed that if i create the hash without an ID:

```
User.collection.update(
  { _id: @user.id },
  { :$push => { educations: education } },
  { safe: true }
)
```

and I query the education from the Rails console, the ID will change each time:

```
irb(main):004:0> User.brandon.educations.map(&:id)
 => [BSON::ObjectId('4fb26e13e5be082384000007')]
irb(main):005:0> User.brandon.educations.map(&:id)
 => [BSON::ObjectId('4fb26e13e5be082384000009')]
```

However, if I do this:

```
User.collection.update(
  { _id: @user.id },
  { :$push => { educations: BSON::ObjectId.create_pk(education) } },
  { safe: true }
)
```

The ID is the same each time queried from the console. Because of this, I'm having trouble referencing the education to edit the embedded doc in the browser.

Do I always have to supply a BSON ID when I create an embedded document?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the entire sample document? What do you mean by "the ID will change each time"? Can you show an example of this?

Comment: Updated the doc and the methods used to update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't supply some kind of identifier (it could be a String, an int, etc) in the _id field, then MongoDB will automatically create one for you, to make the document unique (so that it can be looked up by _id). There is normally a unique index on _id, so if the document isn't unique, insertion will fail (or the existing document will be updated instead, etc).

MongoDB's strategy for making the document unique is to use an ObjectID, as these are globally unique. They are also different every time you create one — that's how they are globally unique.

Long story short: if you have a key that makes your document 100% unique already (possibly :school in your example), then store it as _id, and MongoDB will do the hard work for you.

Comment: I've updated the post to better reflect my questions. I would prefer it create it for me. I've been using MongoMapper for some time, and everything has been find when it creates IDs. However, I'm going back to the driver to use atomic updates for embedded docs, which MongoMapper doesn't do well, and I'm confused as to why I can't just have it create the embedded doc ID.

Comment: I just took a look at your update — MongoDB only adds _id in a top level document. This looks like something weird that MongoMapper is doing (I'm not familiar with MongoMapper, unfortunately) to track references between documents for you. Is education stored as a separate entity somewhere else? If so, then my guess is that the _id is the same as the _id property of that education in the other collection.

Comment: Gotcha. I thought all embedded docs would have an ID so that it could be referenced via URL. I was query the educations from the console, it and it must just assign it an ID on the fly if it doesn't have one. I guess I'll just have to go with my latter syntax so that it creates one so I can do the usual CRUD operations on the embedded elements. Thanks!